# restart iteration through a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

I'm trying to restart an iteration through an 2d array. I'm using the following array for testing:

{ {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} }

The result of my toString-method ist 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.
(Iterator with a next-method to get every single value)

What I'm trying to do is to give the method a start and end like (array, 1, 2) to get this result:

6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

My gues is to use a variable that checks the position. But I have no clue how to restart my iteration until this position is reached.

Current code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class IteratorForArray<T> implements Iterator<T> {
private T[][] array;
private boolean istZeilenweise, istVorwaerts, next;
private int zeile, zStart;
private int spalte, sStart, index;
private T wert;

public IteratorFuerArray2(T[][] array, boolean istZeilenweise, boolean istVorwaerts, int zStart, int sStart) {
    this.array = array;
    this.istZeilenweise = istZeilenweise;
    this.istVorwaerts = istVorwaerts;
    this.zStart = zStart;
    this.sStart = sStart;

    if (istVorwaerts) {
        zeile = this.zStart;
        spalte = this.sStart;
    } else {
        zeile = zStart;
        spalte = sStart;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if (istZeilenweise) {
        if (this.istVorwaerts) {
            next = (zeile < this.array.length && spalte < this.array.length);
        } else {
            next = (zeile >= 0) && spalte >= 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (this.istVorwaerts) {
            next = zeile < this.array.length && spalte < this.array.length;
        } else {
            next = zeile >= 0 && spalte >= 0;
        }
    }
    return next;
}

@Override
public T next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
        return null;
    }
    if (this.istZeilenweise == true) { // zeilenweise
        if (this.istVorwaerts) { // vorwärts
            wert = zeilenweiseVor();
        } else { // rückwärts
            wert = zeilenweiseRueck();
        }
    } else { // spaltenweise
        if (this.istVorwaerts) { // vorwärts
            wert = spaltenweiseVor();
        } else { // rückwärts
            wert = spaltenweiseRueck();
        }
    }
    return wert;
}

private void resetVor() {
    if (this.istZeilenweise) { // zeilenweise
        if (spalte == this.array[zeile].length) {
            spalte = 0;
            zeile++;
        }
    } else { // spaltenweise
        if (zeile == this.array[spalte].length) {
            zeile = 0;
            spalte++;
        }
    }
}

private void resetRueck() {
    if (istZeilenweise) { // zeilenweise
        if (spalte < 0) {
            spalte = this.array[zeile].length - 1;
            zeile--;
        }
    } else { // spaltenweise
        if (zeile < 0) {
            zeile = this.array[spalte].length - 1;
            spalte--;
        }
    }
}

public T zeilenweiseVor() {
        while (zeile < this.array.length) {
            while (spalte < this.array[zeile].length) {
                if (this.array[zeile][spalte] != null) {
                    wert = this.array[zeile][spalte];
                    spalte++;
                    resetVor();
                    return wert;
                } else {
                    spalte++;
                    resetVor();
                }
            }
            zeile++;
        }
    return wert;
}

public T zeilenweiseRueck() {
    while (zeile >= 0) {
        while (spalte >= 0) {
            if (this.array[zeile][spalte] != null) {
                wert = this.array[zeile][spalte];
                spalte--;
                resetRueck();
                return wert;
            } else {
                spalte--;
                resetRueck();
            }
        }
        zeile--;
    }
    return wert;
}

public T spaltenweiseVor() {
    while (zeile < this.array.length) {
        while (spalte < this.array[zeile].length) {
            if (this.array[zeile][spalte] != null) {
                wert = this.array[zeile][spalte];
                zeile++;
                resetVor();
                return wert;
            } else {
                zeile++;
                resetVor();
            }
        }
        spalte++;
    }
    return wert;
}

public T spaltenweiseRueck() {
    while (zeile >= 0) {
        while (spalte >= 0) {
            if (this.array[zeile][spalte] != null) {
                wert = this.array[zeile][spalte];
                zeile--;
                resetRueck();
                return wert;
            } else {
                zeile--;
                resetRueck();
            }
        }
        spalte--;
    }
    return wert;
}

public String toString() {
    String ausgabe = "";
    while (hasNext()) {
        ausgabe += next();
        if (hasNext()) {
            ausgabe += ", ";
        } else {
            ausgabe += ".";
        }
    }
    return ausgabe;
}
```

}

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You mean plain array, like `int[][] array` ? To restart iteration from the beginning you would have to create new iterator. Why won't you use plain for loop with iteration variables?

Comment: @Azanx Because OP is trying to create an `Iterator` so that *it* can be used in an *single* enhanced `for` loop to iterate the 2D array as-if it was a flat array.

Answer (score 1):

With all the field and variable names in German, it's a bit hard to follow, but here is the logic:

- Save the starting position (`s1`,`s2`)
- Set index fields (`i1`, `i2`) to start position
- On each call to next, increment `i2`.

  - If end of inner array, reset `i2` to 0 (wrap around) and increment `i1`.
  - If end of outer array, reset `i1` to 0 (wrap around).
- If `i1 == s1 && i2 == s2` you've reached the end, and stop there.

Since `i1 == s1 && i2 == s2` is true at both beginning and end, you need a boolean field to track difference.

---

Since "istVorwaerts" means "isForward", and "istZeilenweise" means "isLinewise", or something like that, you will of course adjust logic described above to handle those 4 cases, same as you are already doing, so that you can iterate the 2D array in all 4 directions.

Given that there is very little shared code between the 4 cases, I'd suggest creating 4 iterator classes instead.

I would also suggest creating a wrapper `Iterable` class, with static factory methods, so you can do something like this to iterate row-wise in reverse direction:

```
for (MyClass obj : IterableArray2.up(myarray, 1, 2)) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: using a do-while, you can avoid the additional check of the beginning of the iteration. However, you do need a check to ensure the first iteration is valid

Comment: @Wietlol What `do-while`? This is a stateful `Iterator` that maintains a current position and forwards (or reverses) the position on each call to `next()`. There is no `do-while` loop. The `Iterator` can be used by an enhanced `for` loop, and is likely the reason for creating the `Iterator`.